# Importing system-wide installed module into Anaconda

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I have an issue with module importing within Anaconda.
I'm using the latest Anaconda 3 installed in my Linux home directory in order to have the latest jupyter, scipy, numpy and so on. 
I also have installed a scientific package (Kwant) for quantum transport  calculations via Ubuntu ppa deb package: the libraries are found in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kwant`

I have set python as python3.4 with alias command and exported environment variables `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kwant` and the same for `LD_LIBRARYPATH`.
When I launch jupyter notebook and execute the first cell with
`import kwant` I get the error message

```
ImportError: No module named 'kwant'
```

Is it possible importing a module which is installed in `/usr` system directory whereas Anaconda is in the `/home directory` ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

change

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kwant
```

to

```
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

And see if that works for you

Comment: If I do that, then it selects an older Tornado version installed via Ubuntu repos and I cannot launch the Ipython shipped with Anaconda. Maybe, I should try setting the path within the Jupyter notebook.

Comment: My problem is that I should remove all system-wide installed Python packages not to have conflict with Anaconda version

Comment: In that case, you really ought to use virtualenv: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: In the end, it's a lot easier using pip install kwant into anaconda default environment after installing build dependencies with apt-get build-dep, so things are kept in separate environments